# count the number of fluctuations between 0 and 1

Tags: r

I have a random sequence of 1 and 0, around 51 values, and I want to count the number of fluctuations between "heads and tails".
To be specific, I have 27 values of 0 and 24 of 1 and I want to know the number of fluctuations between 0 and 1.
I only could get the number of 0's and 1's by this code:

```
coin.tosses[coin.tosses==0]
```

and

```
coin.tosses[coin.tosses==1]
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean with fluctuations? The number of times the values change from 0 to 1 or vise versa?

Answer (score 2):

You can sum the absolute differences equal to one:

```
coin.tosses <- sample(c(0, 1), 51, replace = TRUE)
sum(abs(diff(coin.tosses)) == 1)
```

If you want to count only head to tail or inverse, remove `abs` and check for equality to 1 or -1

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. We can compare every element with it's next element and count the number of times the value is different

```
x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)

sum(x[-1] != x[-length(x)])
#[1] 7
```

The same logic can be applied with `head` and `tail`

```
sum(head(x, -1) != tail(x, -1))
```

`dplyr::lag`

```
sum(x != dplyr::lag(x), na.rm = TRUE)
```

and `data.table::shift`

```
sum(x != data.table::shift(x), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

We can also use `rle` or `rleid` and count the number of unique groups and subtract 1 since we do not want to count unique value at the end of the group.

```
length(rle(x)$lengths) - 1
```

and

```
max(data.table::rleid(x)) - 1
```